# How to add a div inside a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've added several large centered icons on my page, one for a store, one for resources, and one for contact, once clicked they open a drop menu, that I would like fully styled, with divs, images, links, ect.

Basically a webpage inside a dropdown menu.

So far I can't figure it out.

```
<div class="storedrop">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">PATTERNS</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
  <div class="store">
    {% include storecontent.html %}
  </div>
</div>
```

This is most likely a backwards way of doing what I need, but I'm pretty new to wed dev.. This is my first website.

I googled for the past two hours and can't find the answer...any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: First two answers when googeling `html includes`. [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp), [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/) - the jquery solution already posted below is surly the most simple to implement.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using jquery, please try with below code, your html page will be loaded:

```
$( ".store" ).load( "storecontent.html" );
```

Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.
You can reach more detail [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)